# Blocking threads in java - to be avoided?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

What is the difference between blocked and waiting threads in terms of resources consumed(cpu cycles et al).
Would I rather invoke notify() to wake up one thread and leave others in waiting state;or call notifyall() to have all the waiting threads move into blocked state(except the one that successfully transitioned to runnable)?

Comment: This site [discusses the same issues](http://www.coderanch.com/t/425685/threads/java/Blocked-vs-Waiting-Thread) and may be helpful. Is there any chance you can avoid directly using `wait` and `notify` and rely on some of the classes from the `java.util.concurrent` package?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the difference between blocked and waiting threads in terms of resources consumed(cpu cycles et al).

None.  A thread consumes no CPU cycles while it is waiting or blocked.

> Would I rather invoke notify() to wake up one thread and leave others in waiting state;or call notifyall() to have all the waiting threads move into blocked state(except the one that successfully transitioned to runnable)?

If `notifyAll()` is going to result in all but one of the waiting threads going back into the wait state ... and `notify()` will wake up the thread that will be able continue ... then `notify()` is better.  Each time a thread is woken up will cost CPU time.

However, if you are struggling with understanding wait/notify/notifyAll and their performance characteristics, you'd be better off using one of the higher level concurrency classes provided by the `java.util.concurrent` package.